# WPF - Row Validation?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a layout grid with 12 rows. Each row contains a datepicker, 2 - timepickers, a label, and 2 - textboxes. Each control is in a separate column. In order to submit the form all controls in the first row have to have a value (validating this is easy...). The remaining 11 rows are optional however, if any of the controls in the row have a value, all of the controls in the row must have a value. How can I go about applying validation to each of the optional rows without a convoluted, hard coded conditional statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such a case by using .NET Validation Framework for WPF, have a look at this question:
[WPF Data Binding and Validation Rules Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646/wpf-data-binding-and-validation-rules-best-practices)

Greetings,