# Strange order of firing of Validation.Error event - Added fired before Removed

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I am getting strange behavior as far as order of firing of Validation.Error event is concerned. According to the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), **the data binding engine first removes any ValidationError that may have been added to the Validation.Errors attached property of the bound element**. Accordingly, the ValidationErrorEvent for **Removed** should be fired prior to the **Added**, but strangely in my case the **Added** event gets fired before the **Removed** event. Here is the code that I am using.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="txtGroupsPerRow" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="StandardRack.NoOfGroupsPerRow" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <gs:NumericValidationRule PropertyName="No Of Groups Per Row"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding> 
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
private RoutedEventHandler _errorEventRoutedEventHandler;
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    _errorEventRoutedEventHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(ExceptionValidationErrorHandler);
    this.AddHandler(System.Windows.Controls.Validation.ErrorEvent, _errorEventRoutedEventHandler, true); 
}

private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.RemoveHandler(System.Windows.Controls.Validation.ErrorEvent, _errorEventRoutedEventHandler);
    _errorEventRoutedEventHandler = null;
}

//Added fired before Removed
private void ExceptionValidationErrorHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (validationErrorEvent.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added) {
        viewModel.AddValidationError(propertyPath, validationErrorEvent.Error.ErrorContent.ToString());
    }
    else if (validationErrorEvent.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Removed) {
        viewModel.RemoveValidationError(propertyPath);
    }
}
```

Has anyone come across this issue, or is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: I just ran into this same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpressionBase.cs,ed4c784234c49c09), the steps of adding a new validation error before removing an old one

> are carefully ordered to avoid going through a "no error" state while replacing one error with another

Comment: I think my application suffers from the same error. If I enter a non valid value in a textbox the event fires correctly, when I then enter another nonvalid value, I get the EventAction.added event first, and then the EventAction.removed, which resolves the text as totally valid. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? Everyone says they are running into the same thing on this thread but offer no insight to what is wrong or what could help this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind fractor's answer you can try to do a little workaround.
Create some counter that will represent errors count of validated control:

```
int errorCounter = 0;
private void TextBox_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        errorCounter += (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added) ? 1 : -1;
        //here do whatever you want to with you stored information about error
        someControl.IsEnabled = !(errorCounter > 0);
    }
}
```

I know it's kinda old question but I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I read many forums and found that its a MS 3.5 to 4.0 upgrade issue and there is no direct solution. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/590dc1d4-045e-4bdf-a84b-d759a5903633/validationerror-giving-strange-behavior

However you could use below code to take decision

((BindingExpressionBase)e.Error?.BindingInError).HasValidationError

true = if has validation error else false.
It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this event to determine a change in error state, but since they appear out of order (for good reason, see fractor's answer), you should read the Validation.HasErrors property instead.

`var hasErrors = (bool)GetValue(Validation.HasErrorProperty);`

Do this in the same handler, it will always be correct.