# Regular expression to validate a double number in C#

Tags: c#, regex, double

I'm using the following regular expression to validate double numbers.

```
var allowedChars = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$");
```

It seems that the above expression still can not filter the following:

```
001
1....0
1...
..1
1......01
```

How can I avoid these?

Comment: Why aren't you using `double.TryParse()`?

Comment: It matches `001`, but does not match other values you provided. See https://regex101.com/r/yV8gR0/1. You actually allow an empty string, integer or floats, or a dot. I'd use `new Regex(@"^\d*\.?\d+$")`

Comment: Because I don't want the user to enter irrelevant data in the first place. I'm using PreviewTextInput event. So it fires at each key press and won't work when I enter `.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried and I was able to enter `1...` in the text box. It seems it doesn't filter these kinds of patterns.

Comment: I guess you are trying to check one char against the final regex. Use the whole texbox value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I can't understand. I don't want the user to be able to enter for example 1....., how can I check the whole textbox? with which event?

Comment: Do you need a special event to access the WPF texbox text value?

Comment: Whether you use regex or `double.TryParse()`, validation is only useful if you are looking at the entire text. A subset of the text could pass validation even while the whole text value does not. It looks like you are using WPF; both WPF and Winforms have robust text validation mechanisms that you should be using, and in either case using `TryParse()` makes the most sense, since that applies the exact same test that will eventually be used to convert the text to a numeric value. In fact, with the binding done right, WPF will do the validation for you automatically.

Comment: If you need help with some _specific_ aspect of validation not addressed in the marked duplicate, please post a new question with a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're trying to solve, and be sure to describe precisely what specific issue you're having trouble with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks Peter, I will look more into it. I'd appreciate it if you could give me a link to the binding method you are suggesting for validation.

Comment: There's no special link. The default binding behavior is to validate the input as the source data type, and to highlight the control with the default adorner (red outline) if the validation fails. You can add your own validation behavior(s) if you like...there's no one single link, you should research how to validate. A couple of SO topics I have found useful include https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498485/proper-validation-with-mvvm and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596452/passing-state-of-wpf-validationrule-to-view-model-in-mvvm

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you very much Peter. It seems I was going in the wrong direction.