# Autogeneration event to call method, like button command tabitem wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I need to create validation: if all fields are filled

```
IsEnabled=true; //in xaml for next tabItem
```

If not all fields are filled

```
IsEnabled=false; //in xaml for next tabItem
```

I want that validation be always while user see TabItems (Control\Window).
I want something like Button's Command that has

```
public WizardCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
{
   if (execute == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

   this.execute = execute;

   if (canExecute != null)
      this.canExecute = canExecute;
}
```

Button's Command call **WizardCommand(Action execute, Func canExecute)** automatically while button is on form.
How make tabitem work like button with command on mvvm with binding?

Comment: What's the problem? Create `IsEnabled` property in your view model, bind it to `TabItem.IsEnabled`. Then change that property every time, when validation occurs.

Comment: when validation occurs - this is the problem. How to generate this "when validation occurs"

Comment: Call validation method when fields change

Comment: no, i have 50 fields, and i need something like command only

Comment: WPF supports three validation approaches: validation using valudation rules, validation using exceptions, validation using `IDataErrorInfo`. There are many articles/blog entries, which describes these approaches. This question also will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646/wpf-data-binding-and-validation-rules-best-practices

Comment: ... i can't understand, why you do not want to hear me...